# Media query precedence

Tags: css, media-queries

I have the following media queries:

```
@media all and (max-height: 720px) and (min-width:1px) {
    .tabeditor {
        height: 60%;
    }
}

@media all and (max-height: 768px) and (min-width:1px) {
    .tabeditor {
        height: 63%;
    }
}
```

When I run it on 1280X720 I see that the height from query with 768px takes over. Is that correct? I am running it in Chrome.

Thanks for help.

Comment: In case others find this helpful: w3schools recommends we ["Always Design for Mobile First"](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp), starting with mobile styles, and using `min-width` as we scale up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@media all and (max-height: 720px) and (min-width:1px) 
{
    .tabeditor {
        height: 60%;
    }
}
@media all and (max-height: 768px) and (min-height : 721px) and (min-width:1px) 
{
    .tabeditor {
        height: 63%;
    }
}
```

You might also need a  `@media all and (min-height: 769px) and (min-width:1px)`

Comment: Note sure about the down vote. But I am not sure if min-width of 1px is needed here. 769px is a good trick BTW ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's what the specification says.

CSS rules always override previous rules and `max-height: 768px` will always match for heights lower than 720.

Try reversing the order of the selectors.

Comment: How can it override if my screen is only 720px?

Comment: Again, 720 is smaller than 768

Comment: So, if it always overrides how can we make it work for different screens? The last query always takes over. Can you please point me to some online illustrations of how it works?

Comment: I can point you to an online answer (a few inches above this very comment). Did you bother trying?

Comment: CSS rules do not always override previous rules. CSS follows a rule of presedence by the number of CSS points attributed to rules. Overrides are determinted by point presedence first (where !important represents a very high amount of points) and order second.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
@media all and (min-height: 720px) and (min-width:1px) 
{
.tabeditor {
    height: 60%;
}
}
@media all and (min-height: 768px) and (min-width:1px) 
{
.tabeditor {
    height: 63%;
}
}
```

and so when you are on 720px height the 768px media query will not take effect